# Number(e.target.value) converts undefined to 0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, material-ui

```
<TextFieldAdornedWithSelect
                    sx={{ width: 120 }}
                    size={"large"}
                    value={bottle.weight}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      bottle.weight = Number(e.target.value);
                    
                    }}
                    type={"number"}
                    options={["g", "kg", "lbs"]}
                    adornmentprops={{
                      onChange: (e) => {
                        bottle.weightUnit = e.target.value;
                       
                      },
                      value: bottle.weightUnit,
                    }}
                  />
```

Inside the bottle class the weight property defined as:

```
# weight: number = 0;
```

When I hit backspace in TextFieldAdornedWithSelect, The 0 under weight isn’t disappearing when i type a number or hit backspace. I am expecting a placeholder if no value is there in TextFieldAdornedWithSelect, currently it's showing 0 if no value is there. Please, suggest any solution to this

Comment: Could you share code of `TextFieldAdornedWithSelect`?

Comment: add the bottle class too.are you using a class to manage you're state?

Comment: Sounds like `bottle.weight` is not reactive. So yeah it might change but React doesn't know and doesn't rerender